# Is there really a Catholic "blessing for bacon?"

Tags: catholicism, prayer, diet, blessings

The following appeared on my facebook feed today:

> The "what random things do we have short formulated prayers for" game is almost as funny as the "how many bizarre things do we have patron saints of" game.
>
> I seriously just found a blessing for bacon. Specifically for bacon.
>
> "Bless, O Lord, this bacon, that it may be a meritious food for Thy children, and grant that through the invocation of Thy holy name all those who eat of it may obtain prosperity, health, and preservation of their souls, through Christ our Lord. Amen. "

I realize that for Baptists, this is totally acceptable. We can pray about anything, and since potluck is a sacrament, and if you take out the "preservation of their souls," probably has been done.  We can pray about anything. And, we wing it a lot. For Catholics, however, I assume there is a little more rigour around making a prayer "official."

So, several questions came to mind in regards to this question, all centered around the legitimacy of this claim and authentication thereof.

1. Is this actually a thing, or is someone pulling my leg? 
   (Note: [this](https://www.catholic.org/prayers/prayer.php?p=371) link appears to substantiate it)
2. How would I find out?
3. Who within the heirarchy has the ability to declare an official "blessing for bacon?"

Comment: So I Googled - and found this: https://www.catholic.org/prayers/prayer.php?p=371. I have to wonder, is there a patron Saint for this as well?

Comment: @IndigoGirl That prayer [actually included in the question too!] is very similar to AG's quote. But if it were ancient, I would expect a search for "Benedicat Domine hanc lardum" to yield at least one result. It doesn't.

Comment: I think #3 is the most important part of this question; and depending on that answer, the rest of the question may be moot.

Comment: Saint Brigit has a bacon miracle - she was preparing a meal for her family, and fed some of the bacon to her dog, but still had the correct number of pieces to feed everyone in the end. I therefore nominate her as the patron saint of bacon.

Comment: Ha...they don't teach this in ccd where I'm from. Sounds to me like this prayer was written down some where by a drunk Irishman around Christmas time :)))

Comment: But then again...if it was written by a saint...I hope they have a sense of humor :)

Comment: Perhaps its better to sizzle in this life than in the next...ok mea culpa...ill stop ;)

Comment: @AndrewLeach This could just be a fad thing that someone started somewhere once the bacon craze hit full swing.  Question is where ...

Comment: @JamesT Apparently this whole bacon prayer thing yields another interesting find on a Catholic forum - found the answer to the question I had.  If one wants to be rather literal, Saint Anthony the Abbott could be considered the patron Saint for bacon.  He's the patron Saint of animals, pigs/swine. 
http://www.drstandley.com/saints_stanthonytheabbott.shtml

Comment: @CharlesAlsobrook - I never learned that either in catechism class LOL but it would have made it more interesting!

Comment: @IndigoGirl Amen! I'd say that anything "official" would have to go through here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congregation_for_Divine_Worship_and_the_Discipline_of_the_Sacraments Anything else with considerable notice would just be a popular swell of local piety

Comment: @Affable Geek Not to be a curious stickler...but does your church literally define potluck as a "sacrament" or is this just being used as a generic comparative term? My guess is the latter :)

Comment: @charlesalsobrook it was a joke I used during my ordination exam.

Comment: @Affable Geek good stuff! :)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Quite independently of the bacon issue, I wouldn't expect to find much under "Benedicat Domine" ("May he bless, O Lord"). Try "Benedicat Dominus" ("May the Lord bless") or "Benedic Domine" ("Bless, O Lord"). Not that I'd expect to find much bacon there either, but at least you'll find some blessings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I really like this question.

It draws attention to an important point to be made, which is, of all the things explicitly managed by the Church, personal [**prayer**](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p4s1c3a1.htm) is relatively low on the list.

As a Catholic belonging to a predominately Southern Baptist extended family (most of them consider fried chicken a sacrament in lieu of potluck), I must constantly remind myself that the Church can appear from the outside to be rather rigid.

The truth is that, although the Church explicitly defines the rituals surrounding the Sacraments and sacramentals, personal [**devotion and prayer**](http://www.catholic.com/tracts/common-catholic-prayers) is, for the most part wide open.

Can a Catholic pray a spontaneous prayer? Absolutely! – as long as it is not inappropriately interruptive. (e.g. not during functions such as weddings, funerals, Mass, etc.)

Can Catholics “wing” prayers? Sure…I know I have a time or two. My priest does all the time.

In all reality, my blessings aren't that much different than that of my ordained Baptist Brother-in-Law.

Is this “bacon prayer” an “official prayer” of the Catholic Church? No.

From what I can tell, this is, at best, a prayer of a particular localized pious tradition. 
The closest “official prayer” I can find of this nature is found in the [**RITUALE ROMANUM**](http://www.sanctamissa.org/en/resources/books-1962/rituale-romanum/50-blessings-of-animals.html),  which is a collection of the "officially approved" prayers to be used in the Church’s ***official*** rituals.

> Blessings of animals
>
> Lord God, King of heaven and earth, Word of the Father by whom were
>   made all creatures destined for our sustenance; we beg you to look
>   with favor on our lowly condition; and as you have given us assistance
>   in our work and in our needs, so may you bless,   shield, and watch
>   over these animals (this animal) with your mercy and heavenly care.
>   And to us, your servants, be pleased to give everlasting grace
>   together with creature needs, thus enabling us to praise and glorify
>   and offer thanks to your holy name; through Christ our Lord. Amen.

The ***standard*** prayer for blessing soon to be eaten food (including bacon, fried chicken, and even pot-luck) is as follows:

> Bless us Oh Lord and these thy gifts which we are about to receive
>   through thy bounty through Christ Our Lord, Amen.

Wherever you are in the world, this is probably the blessing prayed before *all* Catholic meals.

Even so…this doesn't necessarily have to be prayed over food - given the appropriate situation.

For instance - my 3 years old daughter and 5 years old son do good just to get out:

> In name of da Fater, Son, whole Spirit…tank you Jeus for dis food.
>   Hayman!

We actually let the small children of the family pray the above prayer for all family functions, completely safe from canonical infraction.

All things considered, I’m afraid that what you read in your FB feed was perhaps a slight pseudo-caricature of Catholic devotion.

As for the above “bacon prayer,” I truly hope someone comes up with the origin of this prayer. It will make for a great conversation starter at my next pot-luck Knights of Columbus function.

Answer (score 4):

Searched the [raccolata](http://www.saintsworks.net/books/The%20Raccolta%20-%201910.pdf) for bacon and came up empty. So I'd suspect if there is any bacon blessing, it is a private devotion. Although its adherents are clearly numerous.

The official organization who evaluates popular piety is the Congregation for Divine Worship. And you can read tons about its rules [here](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/ccdds/documents/rc_con_ccdds_doc_20020513_vers-direttorio_en.html).  I'd imagine that if this prayer were made official, unless it was promulgated by them (which it isn't) it would be A. Something instituted by a Bishop for use in his diocese that was "leaked" inappropriately for use in the entire Church or b.) for private use only.

Prayers that are for private use only include those praying for the intercession of those whose causes for Sainthood have been started outside the diocese in which the particular aspiring saint has his or her cult. That would include prayers for folks like G.K. Chesterton which is being spread by the American Chesterton Society, outside the diocese in which his cause is being evaluated.

Comment: The Raccolata is a collection of indulgenced prayers. A blessing like one for pork is not likely to be found therein

Answer (score 3):

**Is there really a Catholic “blessing for bacon?”**

There **seems** to be no liturgically known prayer for bacon that I am able to locate, but I do believe the one named above is real, especially if it comes down to a permitted English translation of the official Latin ***Rituale Romanum*** of the Roman Rite.

It should be pointed out that Latin word [***lardum***](https://latin.english-dictionary.help/english-to-latin-meaning-bacon) may be translated into English as either lard or bacon. Lard is by far the most classical translation.

There is a very traditional liturgical prayer found in the ***Rituale Romanum*** for lard as follows:

> [**Benedictio Lardidi**](http://laudatedominum.net/files/romy.pdf)
>
> V. Adjutórium nostrum in nómine Dómini. R. Qui fecit cælum et terram.
>
> V. Dóminus vobíscum. R. Et cum spíritu tuo.
>
> **Oremus.**
>
> **Oratio:** Béne + dic, Dómine, creatúram istam láridi, ut sit remédium salutáre géneri humáno: et præsta per invocatiónem tui sancti nóminis; ut, quicúmque ex eo súmpserint, córporis sanitátem et ánimæ tutélam percípiant. Per Christum Dóminum nostrum.
>
> R Amen.
>
> *Et aspergatur aqua benedicta.*

It is obvious from your linked source from the **Catholic Online** that someone down the line opted to include a variation for the word lard include the word bbacon. Although, perhaps not official as such, it is still valid. Substituting a word in traditional blessing is of done. However, most most prayers will give a list of things that would be permitted to be substituted.

[Blessing of Bacon or Lard](https://www.catholic.org/prayers/prayer.php?p=371) the Catholic Online goes as follows:

> Bless, O Lord, this lard (or bacon), that it may be an effective remedy for the human race, and grant that through the invocation of Thy holy name all those who eat of it may obtain health of body and protection of their souls. Through Christ our Lord. Amen.

As I mentioned above, there seems to be no known source that validates the substitution of the word lard for bacon.

Knowing that **Deacon Keith Fournier** would not have published something that he could not substantiate, even if he did not mention a source, I am almost sure that this prayer as such does exist.

In fact, although I can not validate the source, I believe it was published in the Latin/English missal of Pope Paul’s of 1965, also known as the [Interim Missal](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/58959/25495).

Having seen this missal first hand, I have no doubt that this prayer as such can be found in within its’ pages.

Besides, in Catholicism almost anything may be blessed. If a prayer can not be found for something, a priest may employ the blessing for ***Ad Omnia*** for things unnamed in the  Roman Ritual:

> [Benediction ad Omnia](http://laudatedominum.net/files/romy.pdf)
>
> *Hæc benedictionis formula adhiberi potest a quovis Sacerdote pro omnibus rebus, quarum specialis benedictio in Rituali Romano non habeatur.*
>
> V. Adjutórium nostrum in nómine Dómini. R. Qui fecit cælum et terram.
>
> V. Dóminus vobíscum. R. Et cum spíritu tuo.
>
> **Orémus.**
>
> **Oratio:** Deus, cujus verbo sanctificántur omnia, bene + dictiónem tuam effúnde super creatúram istam
> (creatúras istas): et præsta, ut,quisquis ea (eis) secúndum legem et voluntátem tuam cum gratiárum actióne usus fúerit, per invocatiónem sanctíssimi nóminis tui, córporis sanitátem et ánimæ tutélam, te auctóre, percípiat. Per Christum Dóminum nostrum.
>
> R. Amen.
>
> *Et aspergatur (vel aspergantur) aqua benedicta.*

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the Catholic Man Show for posting this on Facebook.

[image: Bacon Blessing]

**Blessing of Lard or Bacon**

*V.* Our help is in the name of the Lord
*R.* Who has made heaven and earth
*V.* The Lord be with you.
*R.* And with your spirit.

Let us Pray.

Bless, Lord, this lard (or bacon) which You have made, that it may be a healtful food for mankind. Grand by the invocation of Your holy name that all who partake of it may receive health of body and safety of soul, through Christ our Lord, *R.* Amen

(sprinkle it with holy water)

Miss you Affable Geek! Wish you were here to get a kick out of this.