# The Interim Roman Missal of 1965?

Tags: catholicism, mass, vatican-ii

We all know that Pope Benedict XVI authorized the a more broad usage the Mass according to the usage of the 1962 edition of the Roman Missal in his Motu Proprio [On the use of the Roman liturgy prior  to the reform of 1970](http://w2.vatican.va/content/benedict-xvi/en/motu_proprio/documents/hf_ben-xvi_motu-proprio_20070707_summorum-pontificum.html) of July 7, 2007.

There is a little known fact that Pope Blessed Paul VI on March 7, 1965 authorized a new publication of the Roman Missal. Some call this the actual [Missal of Vatican II](http://blog.adw.org/2015/01/a-look-at-the-actual-mass-of-vatican-ii-the-1965-missal/). This particular edition in some ways allows for and makes several changes to previous editions of the Mass of Pope Pius V. In essence, this edition is the Trdentine Mass with several alterations as can be seen [here](http://southernorderspage.blogspot.ca/2011/08/1965-roman-missal.html).

A copy of this "Vatican II Missal" as approved for the use in the United States of America can be found [here](http://www.ccwatershed.org/media/pdfs/13/11/15/17-54-56_0.pdf) and [here](http://www.ccwatershed.org/media/pdfs/13/11/18/11-49-24_0.pdf).

My question is simply: **Are there any priests or religious communities that use this missal with the approval of Rome?**

Comment: The Ordinariate Use (Divine Worship: The Missal) is very similar to the Interim Rite, particularly in its use of traditional language. But it's not the Interim Missal, which is why this comment is only a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know, the Roman Missal of !965 introduced some changes to the way the Mass of Pope St. Pius V's Mass was celebrated.

Amongst the changes are:

> - The possibility of concelebrating the Mass on days where it would deemed appropriate.
> - The use of the maniple is optional.
> - There was also some shortening of the prayers at the foot of the altar and the omission of the Last Gospel.
> - Use of concelebration on certain occations.

This is the Mass that the monks of the Abbey of Fontgombault use since September 1989. I was a postulant in the abbey when the community received the permission through the Pontifical Commission [Ecclesia Dei](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/ced_documents/rc_con_cfaith_20090930_ecclesia-dei_en.html) at the Vatican. It could also be noted that Cardinal Ratzinger gave several talks on the liturgy in July 2001: *[Looking Again at the Question of the Liturgy with Cardinal Ratzinger: Proceedings of the July 2001 Fontgombault Liturgical Conference](http://Looking%20Again%20at%20the%20Question%20of%20the%20Liturgy%20with%20Cardinal%20Ratzinger:%20Proceedings%20of%20the%20July%202001%20Fontgombault%20Liturgical%20Conference)*

The only clear source of Fontgombalt's usage of the Roman Missal of 1965 is in French:

> A la messe conventuelle, les bénédictins célèbrent selon l’Ordo missae de 1965. Les liturgistes eux-mêmes ont souvent oublié que le pape Paul VI publia un nouvel Ordo cette année-là (lequel Ordo fut très bien accueilli par Mgr Lefebvre).
>
> En effet : le vendredi 7 octobre 2011, près d’un millier de fidèles était réuni dans l’église abbatiale de Fontgombault pour la bénédiction du nouveau Père Abbé succédant au T.R.P. Dom Forgeot qui avait résilié sa charge après 34 années d’abbatiat. Mgr Maillard, Archevêque de Bourges, avait accepté de remettre la mitre et la crosse au T.R.P. Dom Plateau, le nouvel Abbé. A cette occasion, Mgr Maillard a concélébré avec cinq autres évêques ainsi que plusieurs pères abbés… selon la forme de la liturgie Romaine définie par l’Ordo de 1965.
>
> Mais surtout, l’Ordo de 1965 restaurait le rituel de la concélébration qui avait été abandonné au cours du Moyen-Âge. - [L’Abbaye Notre-Dame de Fontgombault : un exemple à suivre pour la « réforme de la réforme »](http://notredamedesneiges.over-blog.com/article-l-abbaye-notre-dame-de-fontgombault-un-exemple-a-suivre-pour-la-reforme-de-la-reforme-100556239.html)

In essence it states the Following:

> The Conventual High Mass is celebrated according to the Ordo of the Mass of 1965...
>
> On Friday, the 7th of October, 2011 in the company of about a thousand faithful were present in the [abbatial church of Fomtgombault](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbaye_Notre-Dame_de_Fontgombault) for the benediction of the new abbot [Dom Jean Plateau, OSB](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Pateau). At this occasion Bishop Maillard concelebrated with five other bishops and several abbots .. according to Roman liturgy of the Ordo of the Mass of 1965.
>
> The Ordo of 1965 restored the rite of concelebration which had been abandoned sometime during the course of the Middle Ages.

Fontgombault's daughter houses also follow this reform.